# How to right align text but still keep it indented to left?

Tags: html, css

I am running with a minor CSS problem. I want to have a dual lined text right aligned but they should be intended in a single line. No matter How long the text in the first line grows, the text "Small" should follow and indent itself to the left with the Long text. Both should be aligned to the right though.

**ACTUAL**

[image]

**EXPECTED**

[image]

My js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykmupf1r/1/)

```
<div>
    <div id="blocker">
        ABCD
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p id="inner">
          <h3>A very very long text</h3>
          <h3>Small</h3>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

#blocker{
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}
#wrapper{
    text-align: right;
    background: grey;
    height: 100px;
}
#inner{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Give `#inner` a fixed width and `float: right`.

Comment: @putvande - i should not have fixed widths anywhere. All should be fluid.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that from your question. What about giving it `width: 30%` since it looks like it has the same width as the green box.

Comment: The problem is that `h3` can't be inside a paragraph. Change your `p` e.g. to `div` remove `text-align: right` and float `#inner` to the right. That's all :) [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/d799fj98/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make these changes in your csss and html:

CSS:

```
#inner{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="inner">
      <h3>A very very long text</h3>
      <h3>Small</h3>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ykmupf1r/6/

Comment: That was pretty fast! Thank you

Comment: @bragboy: glad that i could help, please don't forget to accept it then as Answer!

Comment: There's no need to use `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: left;` inside `#inner`.

Comment: @norin89: div's are in default block elements, so it will take the 100% width of its Parent, as its align is left, so we have to make its display as inline-block, otherwise we won't get the wished layout

Comment: @Rami.Q no, when you float the element it's width sizes to the content width. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/ykmupf1r/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a containing div around the text in the right section like below;

```
<div class="txt">
  <p id="inner"> </p>
  <h3>A very very long text</h3>
  <h3>Small</h3>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

And add styles like below;

```
.txt {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no logical reason at all to put an `<h3>` inside a `<p>`. That's about as un-semantic as you can get. You should use tags to best suit your content. If you don't have any headers, don't use any header tags. Just don't ever put a header inside a paragraph.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ykmupf1r/7/)**

css

```
#blocker{
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}
#wrapper{
    background: grey;
    height: 100px;
}
#inner{
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

html

```
<div>
    <div id="blocker">
        ABCD
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p id="inner">
          A very very long text
            <br/>
          Small
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="blocker">
        ABCD
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p id="inner">
          <h3>A very very long text</h3>
          <h3>Small</h3>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#blocker{
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}
#wrapper{
    text-align: right;
    background: grey;
    height: 100px;
}

#wrapper > h3{ text-align:left}
```

Also you can add a new div for say the margin-left